# JobIntentService as foreground service

Tags: android, foreground-service, jobintentservice

I am working with geofences based on [this Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/geofencing). However, I am finding that geofence transitions are not occurring accurately in the background unless I am in Google Maps or a different location based app. Because of this I am attempting to turn the `JobIntentService` into a foreground service that will receive its own regular location updates.

Could someone explain the lifecycle of the `JobIntentService` and the order in which the methods are called when it is created?

Keep in mind I am using the following classes:

```
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, intent)
    }
}

class GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService : JobIntentService() {
    companion object {
        private const val JOB_ID = 573
        // Convenience method
        fun enqueueWork(context:Context, intent:Intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService::class.java, JOB_ID, intent)
        }
    }
    onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // Make notification and start as a foreground service
        return START_STICKY
    }
    onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        // Handle the geofences
    }
```